# Copying a bunch of files with GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a makefile in which I want to copy a few files from one place to another, e.g.:

- `include/mylib/mylib.h` to `dist/include/mylib/mylib.h`
- `include/mylib/platform/linux/platform.h` to  `dist/include/mylib/platform.h`

This is part of the "install" rule. What comes to my mind is something of the sort:

```
EXTRA_INSTALL += include/mylib/mylib.h=dist/include/mylib/mylib.h
EXTRA_INSTALL += include/mylib/platform/linux/platform.h=dist/include/mylib/platform.h

# All other dependecies (objects, .so, etc.) go through `$(TARGET)`
install: $(TARGET) $(EXTRA_INSTALL)

$(EXTRA_INSTALL):
    @cp $(firstword $(subst =, ,$@)) $(lastword $(subst =, ,$@))

.PHONY: install $(EXTRA_INSTALL)
```

I think it's a sort of a hack, but I couldn't think of a proper way to do it. So is there a better way to achieve the same thing? Note that there's no apparent connection between the input filename and the output one, so a rule of the sort `dist/include/%.h:include/%.h` would not be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following might be more readable (although it adds a little duplication), it has the benefit of updating the files if they happen to have changed.

```
EXTRA_INSTALL := dist/include/mylib/mylib.h dist/include/mylib/platform.h

.PHONY: install
install: $(EXTRA_INSTALL)

dist/include/mylib/mylib.h: include/mylib/mylib.h
dist/include/mylib/platform.h: include/mylib/platform/linux/platform.h

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXTRA_INSTALL): $$^
    cp $^ $@
```

You could also forgo `.SECONDEXPANSION` entirely at the expense of an extra line per file

```
EXTRA_INSTALL := dist/include/mylib/mylib.h dist/include/mylib/platform.h

.PHONY: install
install: $(EXTRA_INSTALL)

dist/include/mylib/mylib.h: include/mylib/mylib.h
    cp $^ $@
dist/include/mylib/platform.h: include/mylib/platform/linux/platform.h
    cp $^ $@
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a horrible hack. Doing this kind of thing is *exactly* what `make` is for, you don't need to invent your own mini-language inside `make`.

Define the `source=target` mapping as a `make` prerequisite instead, then define the recipe for creating it via `cp`:

```
dist/include/mylib/mylib.h: include/mylib/mylib.h 
        cp $^ $@
```

This says creating the file `dist/include/mylib/mylib.h` depends  on the other file (so it will be recreated if the other file changes) and that it should be created by copying it.

The answer from @user657267 shows how to reduce duplication by separating the definition of the dependencies from the recipe for doing the actual copying, so you don't need to repeat the `cp` recipe on every file. However, as the recipe is incredibly simple, I see no harm in just repeating it. You could always replace the recipe with a function call if it got more complicated:

```
CP := cp -f
copy_file := $(CP) $(1) $(2)

dist/include/mylib/mylib.h: include/mylib/mylib.h 
        $(call copy_file,$^,$@)

dist/include/mylib/platform.h: include/mylib/platform/linux/platform.h
        $(call copy_file,$^,$@)
```